# how to get access token without any login?

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, permissions, access-token

In my iPhone app I want to read news feed from public Facebook page but I don't want in the beginning that the user has log in facebook to see wall of page. I try to pass access_token (in url to graph api) but this access token expire.

Thank you in advance

Javier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use your application access token for this which may be one of:

- `YOUR_APP_ID|YOUR_APP_SECRET`
- Application Access Token received from `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
   client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&
   grant_type=client_credentials`

This `access_token` allow you to get any public content available via API which require `access_token`

**Update:**
Using iOS SDK this may looks like:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&
 grant_type=client_credentials" andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: With Graph api, I must do this call: [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token? client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET& grant_type=client_credentials" andDelegate:self]; and I replace the ID, SECRET ID and credentials?

Comment: after I call graph api I have this error in request didFailWithError: "Missing redirect_uri parameter." ... in "client_credentials" value I insert "offline_access" is this correct?... the complete expression that I use is this [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/oauth/access_token?client_id=203887386362743&client_secret=37Xd16ad6a4e31cd66956a58f1a200d6&grant_type=offline_access" andDelegate:self]; I change some characters...

Comment: @user946484, nope, this is wrong. You should only replace `YOUR_APP_ID` and `YOUR_APP_SECRET`. BTW, you better remove this comment in a hurry and **reset your application secret**!!! This is something you should keep secret and not share with anyone!

Comment: Thanks Juicy, I think that some is wrong... and no problem, I change severals characters from my appId and Secret code before I wrote in my post... I hope with your help I can solve this problem, thanks again!

Comment: Excuse me for so many questions but my code still doesn't work. Now when I call to graph api in order to get access_token I haven't any error, but access_token is not received. After I call graph api how to get access_token?, I see that never entry in fbDidLogin... are there any event referred to the authorization process?

Comment: Hello, I am trying to get the post of a public Facebook page without login in it. I am trying to get the access token by this method but when I call to the post I the API Graph say always the same error: An access token is required to request this resource. Could you help me please?