# Get post from a Facebook Page without login

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the post of a Facebook Page throw iOS API and I can't do it without login before (without access token). Is there any kind of solution to make this? Does anyone know it?

The App report me the follow error:

```
An access token is required to request this resource.
```

**UPDATE**

I generate one access token with this structure: APPID|APPSECRET and give it an expiration date. With this, I can access to the public data of my Page :)

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0):

Graph API Documentation seys:

```
posts [..] any valid access_token or user access_token
```

More informations you can find there http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

Here is live example http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=19292868552%2Fposts

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I haven't got access_token because I don't want to make one login :(

Answer (score 0):

+1 well... facebook data is all about "user", therefore you always need **valid access_token**

there are few exceptions though,
for example, you can display user profile picture without token,
see example;
https://graph.facebook.com/100001789213579/picture?type=large

Comment: I have seen this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710636/how-to-get-access-token-without-any-login) but when I get this kind of access token I have the same fail :(